# Where do I run the setspn command?

Tags: kerberos, windows-authentication, domaincontroller, spn

I am trying to add a Service Principal Name with the below command, which I am using for Windows Authentication.

```
setspn –a HTTP/Kerberos.com domain\username
```

I have a site running on IIS Server which is running on windows 2008 server connected to Domain Controller machine.

Do I have to run the `setspn` command on the IIS server or on the Domain Controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run it on either machine as long as the login is privileged. The only difference is the amount of time it takes to propagate through the network.

**Domain Controller Machine** - will help propagate through the network faster but than it means that IIS server machine might not recognize the change right away. Hence, you might have to wait for ~30 mins before restarting the server after making changes to SPN.

***-- PREFERRED* -- IIS Server Machine** - changing the SPN here will allow you to continue working with the services. Will take ~30 mins for rest of the network to realize the change, which usually isn't an issue.